# Does the Lévy collapse obey this nice characterization?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

This question is related to an issue in my answer to Monroe Eskew's question on the [failure of Cantor-Bernstein for the Lévy collapse](https://mathoverflow.net/a/159519/1946).

**Question.** Is the  Lévy collapse $\text{Coll}(\omega,\lt\kappa)$ of an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ the unique forcing notion (up to forcing equivalence) which is $\kappa$-c.c., has a dense set of size $\kappa$ and which collapses all infinite cardinals below $\kappa$ to $\omega$?

An analogous fact is known and often used in the case of $\text{Coll}(\omega,\theta)$, which is the unique forcing notion of size $|\theta|$ necessarily collapsing $\theta$ to $\omega$, and a proof of this can be found for example as (folklore) lemma 18 of my paper [Structural connections between a forcing class and its modal logic](http://jdh.hamkins.org/a-forcing-class-and-its-modal-logic/), and elsewhere.

Comment: Question answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/121352/resembling-the-levy-collapse/151194#151194.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate. Or should I just delete it?

Comment: Seems no reason not to delete it.